# Bootstrap 3: text-align change at breakpoint?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there a built-in way in Bootstrap 3.x to set/remove a class like "text-right"?

For example, I have a column `<div class="col-md-6 text-right">` but at xs size I don't want the text-right to apply.

I know how to do this with my own classes/media queries but was wondering if there was something simple built in.

Comment: I believe that you need to apply an additional class and use that to set the text alignment.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

These are available in Bootstrap 4: [Text Alignment](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/text/#text-alignment)

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="text-center">
  <p class="text-left">Left aligned text on all viewport sizes.</p>
  <p class="text-center">Center aligned text on all viewport sizes.</p>
  <p class="text-right">Right aligned text on all viewport sizes.</p>

  <p class="text-sm-left">Left aligned text on viewports sized SM (small) or wider.</p>
  <p class="text-md-left">Left aligned text on viewports sized MD (medium) or wider.</p>
  <p class="text-lg-left">Left aligned text on viewports sized LG (large) or wider.</p>
  <p class="text-xl-left">Left aligned text on viewports sized XL (extra-large) or wider.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: And in Bootstrap 5 "left" is replaced by "start" e.g. `text-sm-start`, and "right" by "end".

Answer (score 4):

Nope. This has been proposed a few times (e.g. https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/11292 , https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/9408 ), but has so far been rejected. It's the sort of thing that'd be very appropriate for a CSS/Sass/Less add-on library for Bootstrap though.